# What does action mean in auroradb

Tags: amazon-aurora

I have set up an aurora database in **aws** and in one column, there is `1 action`. I do not understand the meaning of this. What does it mean?

Comment: Without a screenshot of what you're seeing, I'm guessing that you're looking at the pending maintenance actions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Maintenance.html